# Activiti function that returns system date

Tags: java, spring-boot, activiti

I'm using activiti and spring boot and I want to find a way to get system to use it in sequence flow condition.
Can anyone help me please ? 
Thank you so much

Comment: Can you share the code you tried so far so we can help you